# Storing Binary Data in Database for Security

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to secure my online transactions a bit more.

The process I am using for online transactions is:
1. User generates order
2. User redirects to bank to pay (i.e. paypal)
3. Bank (paypal) contacts a .php page (Paypal IPN) to tell me the order has gone through.
4. Users order has gone through.

In every transaction I generate, I create a `sha512` string out of the data.  I want to store this in the database, to authenticate the order information when the PayPal IPN contacts me to tell me that the order is complete.

In order to save database space, I recently read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828982/1445985)  and thought maybe it would be good to store the string in a binary column.  The question I have is how do I do this with PHP?

So say I have a string:

`A99ACAF1FA7337F451C344C84F6800037F17EABBC32073ECEA6688B4BAD116BDB288B0D24DE7DD5C53E26A0B41242B2D2D065EDFDA5C16B4706CD5DC57226580`

In PHP, how do I convert that to a binary value so that I can store it in the database? And will it still be unique like the above string?  The best I can think to do is the PHP string `pack`, but I am unsure how to use it. Or whether it's the right way to use it.  Normally I would just store the above hash into a `VARCHAR(512)` but I want to keep database size down, and 512 characters seems like a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo hash('sha512', 'hash_string', true);
```

The third argument is `raw_output`: when set to TRUE, outputs raw binary data.  ([doc](http://php.net/manual/it/function.hash.php)). Since there's a one to one correspondence between hexits and their binary value, you don't lose "uniqueness".

The length is always a 64 byte string. But if you write the hash in hexits, then it will be 128 characters, **not 512**.

Comment: So.. I can take that `raw_output` and write it directly to the database?

Comment: sure, you can. just use a field `VARBINARY` if you do that in mysql

Comment: Okay i'm having problems with PDO, do I need to bind the data in a weird way? Simply adding it into prepared variables doesnt seem to take.

Comment: Not to my knowledge; what's exactly the problem?

Comment: This is what I got: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`hash` = '½¡³Òÿ?†ƒhwé Ö Å¬p_QOz 
´ÞÍx|)¥2E9#iuõVI‘Ø€' `